# How to deal with user permissions in single page application

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, client, server

I'm working on a single page enterprise application with a pretty complex logic about user permissions. The huge part of it works entirely on client communicating with backend server using AJAX sending JSON back and forth. The tricky part is that I need to implement permission mechanism as on per-entity basis, and I dont know how to do it the right way.

To explain myself clearly here the example code, I have 2 entity classes on the backend `User` and `Node`:

```
class User {
    Long id;
}
class Node {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Status status;
    Node parent;
    List<User> admins;
}
enum Status {
    STATUS_1, STATUS_2
}
```

I send JSON of parent node to the server:

```
{id: 1, name: "Node name 1", status: 'STATUS_1'}
```

And recieve JSON with a bunch of child nodes:

```
[
    {id: 11, name: "Node name 1.1", status: 'STATUS_1'}, 
    {id: 12, name: "Node name 1.2", status: 'STATUS_1'}
]
```

On the client they are displayed in a tree-like structure, like this:

[image: UI]

Now the tricky part:

1. Simple user that works with application can see tree, but can't change anything.
2. User can change node name if he is among `admins` of node or any of its *parent* nodes.
3. Admins can also change status of node, from `STATUS_1` to `STATUS_2`, but only if all *child* nodes has `STATUS_2` status.
4. There is a list of super adminstrators that can do whatever they want: change properties of any node, change status as they want.

So somehow, during rendering of the tree on the client, I need to know what user can or cannot do with each of the node on the page. I can't just assign user a role within a whole application because user rights vary from one node to another. Also I can't see whole picture on the client side because child nodes may be not loaded. **How can I manage user permissions in situation like this? What's the proper way or pattern to use?**

Should I attach some role object to each node, or maybe a bunch of flags representing what user can or cannot do like that:

```
{ 
    id: 12, 
    name: "Node name 1.2", 
    status: "STATUS_1", 
    canChangeName: true,
    canChangeStatus: false
}
```

That looks pretty silly to me.

Comment: I actually like the flag approach. Everything is figured out when the tree is created, so all the UI has to do is read the flags.  Makes UI implementation straightforward, makes testing easy.

Comment: @dbugger until there are just a few of them its OK, but there can be a huge variety of tasks you can perform with entities, so it ends with dozens of flags for each very little task you can perform on the page with entity. Also there are cases when you cannot represent permissions with just true or false, in my example there are just 2 statuses but there can be much more, so for each status I need to know does user can select it or not.

Comment: Given your constraints, there is no easy way to accomplish this without simplifying and/or abstracting your permissions.  I'd wager very few of these tasks are independent of all the others, and are often turned on or off in groups. I'd make every attempt to get it so your UI can just check a flag or two to do its business.

Answer (score 2):

I usually solve complex (and not so complex) permission-based tasks in the application using ACL classes.

I have simple, lighweight classes, that take a model, permissions for which are being checked, and a user object into a constructor. They have a bunch of methods with names `canXXXX()`. These methods can optionally take some parameters also if that is needed.

If you have the same model classes on front and back, you even might be able to reuse ACLs in both cases.

Can you use this approach?

Comment: Thaks for reply. The problem with that approach is that these ACL classes need to be duplicated on front (JS) and back end (for example, Java). So unless I'm using something like node.js I can't realy reuse them.